# I am trying to import my cleaned data from excel, but every time I attempt to load, source, or read.csv I get these? Any tips on how I can fix it?

Tags: r, csv, import

```
    source("~/Downloads/birthcontrol.csv")
Error in source("~/Downloads/birthcontrol.csv") : 
  ~/Downloads/birthcontrol.csv:1:4: unexpected ','
1: age,
       ^
    source("~/Downloads/birthcontrol.csv")
Error in source("~/Downloads/birthcontrol.csv") : 
  ~/Downloads/birthcontrol.csv:1:4: unexpected ','
1: age,
       ^
    load("~/Downloads/birthcontrol.csv")
Error in load("~/Downloads/birthcontrol.csv") : 
  bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘birthcontrol.csv’ has magic number 'age,b'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated 
    data -> read.csv("~/Downloads/birthcontrol.csv")
Error in read.csv("~/Downloads/birthcontrol.csv") <- data : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Comment: Use `read.csv()` instead of `source()` to import data from a CSV file into R.

Comment: Also, if your goal is to import data directly from Excel, you don't need to save that data into CSV files first.  You can import directly from Excel into R with `readxl::read_excel()`.

Comment: @DanY I tried that but I keep getting error messages

Comment: @DanY                                                                                                    > readxl::read_excel("birthcontrolpsych.csv")
Error: `path` does not exist: ‘birthcontrolpsych.csv’
> data -> read.csv("~/Downloads/birthcontrolpsych.csv")
Error in read.csv("~/Downloads/birthcontrolpsych.csv") <- data : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
> readxl::read_excel("birthcontrolpsych")
Error: `path` does not exist: ‘birthcontrolpsych’